# Processing a large file using spring batch

Tags: spring-batch

I have a large file which may contain 100K to 500K records. I am planning to use chunk oriented processing and my thought is

1) Split the large file into smaller based on the count let say 10K in each file.

2) If there are 100K records then I will get 10 files each containing 10K reocrds

3) I would like to partition these 10 files and would like to process using 5 threads. I am thinking to use custom **MultiResourcePartioner**

4) The 5 threads should process all the 10 files created in split process.

5) I don't want to create same number of threads equal to file count as in that case I may face memory issues. What I am looking is whatever the number of files I would like to process them using only 5 threads (I can increase based on my requirements).

Expert could you let me know this can be achieved using spring batch? If yes could you please share pointers or reference implementations

Thanks in advance

The working job-config xml

```
<description>Spring Batch File Chunk Processing</description>

<import resource="../config/batch-context.xml" />

<batch:job id="file-partition-batch" job-repository="jobRepository" restartable="false">        
    <batch:step id="master">
        <batch:partition partitioner="partitioner" handler="partitionHandler" />
    </batch:step>
</batch:job>

<batch:step id="slave">
    <batch:tasklet>
        <batch:chunk reader="reader" processor="compositeProcessor"
            writer="compositeWriter" commit-interval="5">
        </batch:chunk>
    </batch:tasklet>
</batch:step>

<bean id="partitionHandler" class="org.springframework.batch.core.partition.support.TaskExecutorPartitionHandler">
    <property name="taskExecutor" ref="taskExecutor"/>
    <property name="step" ref="slave" />
    <property name="gridSize" value="5" />
</bean>

<bean id="partitioner" class="com.poc.partitioner.FileMultiResourcePartitioner">
    <property name="resources" value="file:/Users/anupghosh/Documents/Spring_Batch/FilePartitionBatch/*.txt" />
    <property name="threadName" value="feed-processor" />
</bean>

<bean id="taskExecutor" class="org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor">
    <property name="corePoolSize" value="5" />
    <property name="maxPoolSize" value="5" />
</bean>

<bean id="reader" class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemReader" scope="step">
    <property name="resource" value="#{stepExecutionContext['fileName']}" />

    <property name="lineMapper">
        <bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.mapping.DefaultLineMapper">
        <property name="lineTokenizer">
            <bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.DelimitedLineTokenizer">
                <property name="delimiter" value="|"/>
                <property name="names" value="key,docName,docTypCD,itemType,itemNum,launchDate,status" />
            </bean>
        </property>
        <property name="fieldSetMapper">
            <bean class="com.poc.mapper.FileRowMapper" />
        </property>
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="validatingProcessor" class="org.springframework.batch.item.validator.ValidatingItemProcessor">
    <constructor-arg ref="feedRowValidator" />
</bean>

<bean id="feedProcesor" class="com.poc.processor.FeedProcessor" />

<bean id="compositeProcessor" class="org.springframework.batch.item.support.CompositeItemProcessor" scope="step">
    <property name="delegates">
        <list>
            <ref bean="validatingProcessor" />
            <ref bean="feedProcesor" />
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="recordDecWriter" class="com.poc.writer.RecordDecWriter" />

<bean id="reconFlatFileCustomWriter" class="com.poc.writer.ReconFileWriter">
    <property name="reconFlatFileWriter" ref="reconFlatFileWriter" />
</bean>

<bean id="reconFlatFileWriter" class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemWriter" scope="step">
    <property name="resource" value="file:/Users/anupghosh/Documents/Spring_Batch/recon-#{stepExecutionContext[threadName]}.txt" />
    <property name="shouldDeleteIfExists" value="true" />
    <property name="lineAggregator">
        <bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.DelimitedLineAggregator">
            <property name="delimiter" value="|" />
            <property name="fieldExtractor">
                <bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.BeanWrapperFieldExtractor">
                    <property name="names" value="validationError" />
                </bean>
            </property>
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="compositeWriter" class="org.springframework.batch.item.support.CompositeItemWriter">
    <property name="delegates">
        <list>
            <ref bean="recordDecWriter" />
            <ref bean="reconFlatFileCustomWriter" />
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="feedRowValidator" class="org.springframework.batch.item.validator.SpringValidator">
    <property name="validator">
        <bean class="com.poc.validator.FeedRowValidator"/>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Comment: You really have the process laid out correctly.  What is your specific question?

Comment: Thanks @MichaelMinella for responding in short time span. My question is: If I have 10 files after split process (could be more) how I will process those files using 5 threads? More specific how I will partition those files so that 5 thread will process all these 10 files.

Comment: The `MultiResourcePartitioner` is the right way to create the partitions.  From there, using the `TaskExecutionPartitionHandler`, you'd control how many threads are used via the configuration of your `TaskExecutor`.  By default it uses the `SyncTaskExecutor` but we expect you to configure something else like the `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor`.  In that `TaskExecutor` you can configure max threads, etc.

Comment: Many thanks @MichaelMinella following your suggestion finally I got it working. I appreciate your help.  I have edited my answer and added working version of my job config xml as there is a size limitations in comments. May be that will be useful for someone. Please let me know how to accept the 'Answer'

Comment: @Anup how you are splitting file ?

Comment: @AnupGhosh How you are splitting file ? also could you please show implementation of FileMultiResourcePartitioner

Answer (score 3, accepted):

was able to solve this using MultiResourcePartitioner. below are java config

```
@Bean
    public Partitioner partitioner() {
        MultiResourcePartitioner partitioner = new MultiResourcePartitioner();
        ClassLoader cl = this.getClass().getClassLoader();
        ResourcePatternResolver resolver = new PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver(cl);
        Resource[] resources = resolver.getResources("file:" + filePath + "/"+"*.csv");     
        partitioner.setResources(resources);
        partitioner.partition(10);      
        return partitioner;
    }

    @Bean
    public TaskExecutor taskExecutor() {
        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor taskExecutor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        taskExecutor.setMaxPoolSize(4);
        taskExecutor.afterPropertiesSet();
        return taskExecutor;
    }   

    @Bean
    @Qualifier("masterStep")
    public Step masterStep() {
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("masterStep")
                .partitioner(ProcessDataStep())
                .partitioner("ProcessDataStep",partitioner())   
                .taskExecutor(taskExecutor())
                .listener(pcStressStepListener)
                .build();
    }


    @Bean
    @Qualifier("processData")
    public Step processData() {
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("processData")
                .<pojo, pojo> chunk(5000)
                .reader(reader)             
                .processor(processor())
                .writer(writer)         
                .build();
    }



    @Bean(name="reader")
    @StepScope
    public FlatFileItemReader<pojo> reader(@Value("#{stepExecutionContext['fileName']}") String filename) {

        FlatFileItemReader<pojo> reader = new FlatFileItemReader<>();
        reader.setResource(new UrlResource(filename));
        reader.setLineMapper(new DefaultLineMapper<pojo>() {
            {
                setLineTokenizer(new DelimitedLineTokenizer() {
                    {
                        setNames(FILE HEADER);


                    }
                });
                setFieldSetMapper(new BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper<pojo>() {
                    {
                        setTargetType(pojo.class);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
        return reader;
    }
```

Comment: Also need to add taskExecutor.setCorePoolSize(4) & taskExecutor.setQueueCapacity(8) to make multi-threading work.